# What i am doing wrong here in this code of python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, python-multithreading, http-proxy

I am trying to create a proxy checker in python3 and everything is working fine until than i didn't introduce multi-threading in it to make it fast now it is giving me error and i am not able to understand why it is so

```
import requests
import threading

#DECLARING ALL VARIABLES

proxy_api="https://api.proxyscrape.com/?request=getproxies&proxytype=http&timeout=50&country=all&ssl=all&anonymity=all"
raw_proxy = []
live_proxy = []

#Declaring ALL COUNTERS
proxy_Counter = 0 

def main():
    pass

def fetch_proxy():
    global raw_proxy
    res = requests.get(proxy_api)
    raw_proxy = res.text.splitlines()
    print(len(raw_proxy))
    return raw_proxy

def check_proxy():
    global raw_proxy
    global live_proxy
    global proxy_Counter
    while proxy_Counter < len(raw_proxy):
        try:
            proxyDict = { 
                          "https"  : "https://"+raw_proxy[proxy_Counter], 
                          "http" : "http://"+raw_proxy[proxy_Counter],
                        }
            res = requests.get("http://httpbin.org/ip",proxies=proxyDict,timeout=3)
            print(f"Proxy Live {raw_proxy[proxy_Counter]}")
            live_proxy.append(raw_proxy[proxy_Counter])
            proxy_Counter+=1
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Dead Proxy {raw_proxy[proxy_Counter]}")
            proxy_Counter+=1

    print(len(live_proxy))
    return live_proxy

fetch_proxy()
threads = []
for _ in range(10):
    t = threading.Thread(target=check_proxy)
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)


for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide any error or stacktrace but it looks like you're getting an `IndexError`, this is because your loop is incorrect. Imagine you got back 100 proxies, your current loop will go from 0 to 100, however, that is 101 entries and not 100; because 0 is the first index. A quick solution is to change this line so that it is one less (0-99 = 100 iterations):

```
while proxy_Counter < len(raw_proxy) - 1:
```

However, if your aim is to speed up the process of checking the proxies, your code will have the opposite effect because for each thread you create, you're checking each proxy again so now you have x10 the redundancy. It would be better to use a [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor) and evenly distribute the proxies to your threads and set a maximum amount of threads so that you're not overloading the server.

Comment: Can You Help me a little bit more regarding it that how to evenly distribute my proxies

Comment: Search around for examples for inspiration, such as [this one](https://github.com/demogorgonz/Multithreaded-Python-Proxy-Checker-for-Google-access/blob/master/proxy.py) that uses a [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html). There are lots of resources out there for multithreading.